# nuSOAP: Header Authentication on server side

Tags: php, nusoap

Can any one please advice how to parse nuSOAP headers and checking the `username/password/Signature` from the below SOAP Request

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:wsa="http://admin.example.com">
      <Username>testuser</Username>
      <Password>test123456</Password>
      <Signature>5595610031002</Signature>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

i.e: i need to parse this header on server side and validate the credentials for every request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not sure but i found an alternative to track the credentials by using the following code.
let me explain.

The code `$sSoapRequest = file_get_contents('php://input');` which returns the entire SOAP request to the server side...

The following 2 functions helps me to bring out the values..

```
function doAuthenticate()
{
    $sSoapRequest = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if(isset($sSoapRequest))
    {
        $sUsername = hookTextBetweenTags($sSoapRequest, 'Username');
        $sPassword = hookTextBetweenTags($sSoapRequest, 'Password');
        $sSignature = hookTextBetweenTags($sSoapRequest, 'Signature');
        if($sUsername=='testuser' && $sPassword=='test123456' && $sSignature=='5595610031002')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
function hookTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

and, use `doAuthenticate()` method for every process in server side.